# Need help in writing query to map value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables one is **useremails** and **instdomains**.Table structure as follows

```
CREATE TABLE instdomains (
  DomainID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  DomainMask varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  InstitutionID int(11) NOT NULL,
  shareddomain tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  masterdomainid int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (DomainID)
);

CREATE TABLE useremails (
 EmailID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UserID int(11) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  Verified tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (EmailID),
);
```

Here I want to add new column **InstitutionID** to **useremails** table which should map with **instdomains** table by comparing **domainmask** value with **email** value from **useremails** table.

**Table data of instdomains as follow**

| INSTDOMAINS |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DomainID | DomainMask | InstitutionID | shareddomain | masterdomainid |
| 1 | harvard.edu | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | princeton.edu | 19 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | brown.edu | 196 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | bu.edu | 217 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | wustl.edu | 287 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | mcmaster.ca | 326 | 0 | 0 |

**Table data of useremails as follows**

| USEREMAILS |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EmailID | UserID | email | Verified |
| 1 | 15 | antonio_gomes@hms.harvard.edu | 1 |
| 2 | 19 | lcwong@princeton.edu | 1 |
| 3 | 56 | jason_ziplow@Brown.edu | 1 |
| 4 | 33 | clsmith@bu.edu | 1 |
| 5 | 45 | menneris@wustl.edu | 1 |
| 6 | 65 | peiy@univmail.cis.mcmaster.ca | 1 |

so here the data in **email** column from **useremails** table compare with **domainmask** column of **instdomains** table and then it should update **institutionid** on **useremails** table by comarimg with **instdomain** table with respect to **domainmask** value. sample output as follows

| SAMPLE OUTPUT |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EmailID | UserID | email | Verified | InstitutionID |
| 1 | 15 | antonio_gomes@hms.harvard.edu | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 19 | lcwong@princeton.edu | 1 | 19 |
| 3 | 56 | jason_ziplow@Brown.edu | 1 | 196 |
| 4 | 33 | clsmith@bu.edu | 1 | 217 |
| 5 | 45 | menneris@wustl.edu | 1 | 287 |
| 6 | 65 | peiy@univmail.cis.mcmaster.ca | 1 | 326 |

Here comparision of **email** and **domainmask** will be, the data after **'@'** or **'.'** symbol from **email** should compare with **domainmask** value.FOr example **'a@test.com'** should match to **'test.com'** or if **'example.test.com'** were present it'd match to that.

For example **'abc@utest.com'** should not map to **'test.com'** because we have **u** after **@** symbol

I have used below concept

**substr(u.email, locate("@", u.email) +1) regexp concat("(^|[.])", replace(DomainMask, ".", "[.]"), "$")**

Please let me know if any suggestion

Comment: will be easier to help if you set up https://www.db-fiddle.com/ along with some sample data and expected output.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9DtLRrPR1s2fDJynRMLUtV/0   sampe data has been updated ,for sample output refer main question because here we need to use query for that I need help @HarshGundecha

Answer (score 1):

For desired output in a question:

```sql
SELECT useremails.*, instdomains.InstitutionID
FROM useremails
JOIN instdomains ON useremails.email LIKE CONCAT('%', instdomains.DomainMask);
```

or, for a comment "How it compare only after '@', '.' ?"

```sql
SELECT useremails.*, instdomains.InstitutionID
FROM useremails
JOIN instdomains ON instdomains.DomainMask = SUBSTRING_INDEX(useremails.email, '@', -1);
```

And one more variant - the domain from `instdomains` in `email` domain must be preceded with `.` or `@` only:

```sql
SELECT useremails.*, instdomains.InstitutionID
FROM useremails
JOIN instdomains ON useremails.email REGEXP CONCAT('^.*[.@]', instdomains.DomainMask, '$');
```

And create/fill referenced column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE instdomains
ADD INDEX (InstitutionID);

ALTER TABLE useremails
ADD COLUMN InstitutionID INT;

UPDATE useremails
JOIN instdomains ON useremails.email REGEXP CONCAT('^.*[.@]', instdomains.DomainMask, '$')
SET useremails.InstitutionID = instdomains.InstitutionID;

ALTER TABLE useremails
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_InstitutionID FOREIGN KEY (InstitutionID) REFERENCES instdomains (InstitutionID);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dbc18a6cc580b85a3b507fb01c81ed09

Comment: How it compare only after '@', '.' ? ,I need to update institutionid value by comparing domainmask value,so please help me with update query

Comment: I am adding new column institutionid in useremails table and I want that value to be updated by comparing email and domainmask value from 2 table.after @ or . value in email should match with domainmask value and that instituionid value to be updated on useremails table

Comment: If you see sample data  email antonio_gomes@hms.harvard.edu where hms.harvard.edu is comapared with instdomains domainmask value and updated instituionid in useremails table.How we can achieve by query?

Comment: @Moolya *How it compare only after '@', '.' ?* If you do so then the output won't desired one - `EmailID=1` will be removed from it because `'hms.harvard.edu' != 'harvard.edu'`. The same for `EmailID=6`. But if you want nevertheless then use `.. ON instdomains.DomainMask = SUBSTRING_INDEX(useremails.email, '@', -1)`. Answer updated. *I want that value to be updated* Convert SELECT to UPDATE.

Comment: @Moolya *If you see sample data email antonio_gomes@hms.harvard.edu where hms.harvard.edu is comapared with instdomains domainmask value* There is **no** the value `hms.harvard.edu` in `INSTDOMAINS` table.

Comment: sorry it should be harvard.edu comapring with domain mask value i.e after @ or . @Akina

Comment: @Moolya Third varian added - check.

Comment: So I can use this query to update right?   update useremails set InstitutionID=(select instdomains.InstitutionID
FROM useremails
JOIN instdomains ON useremails.email COLLATE utf8_general_ci REGEXP CONCAT('^.*[.@]', instdomains.DomainMask, '$'));

Comment: @Moolya: No join. Refer to the updating row in the subquery. `update useremails set InstitutionID = (select instdomains.InstitutionID FROM instdomains WHERE useremails.email COLLATE utf8_general_ci REGEXP CONCAT('^.*[.@]', instdomains.DomainMask, '$'));`

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Multiple-table UPDATE should be more clear I think.

Comment: update query throwing error Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row @ThorstenKettner

Comment: @Moolya UPDATE added.

Comment: Is it possible to update instituionid column of useremails table? i used above query but getting error @Akina

Comment: @Moolya Please see posted code and provided fiddle (last code block). *Is it possible to update instituionid column of useremails table?* It is absolutely impossible to update the column which not exists. It must be created previouslty.

Comment: @Akina I have already added column  institutionid in useremails with default value 0 and   and now I have to update by referring instdomains

Comment: @Moolya *I have already added column institutionid in useremails with default value 0* If you will create FK reference then replace DEFAULT value and set it to NULL.

Comment: @Moolya: If the subquery in my update statement returns more than one row, then you have two domains matching one user email. That must not be, so you should find out, what that problem is. You can find the multi matches with `select ue.email, group_concat(d.domainmask) from useremails ue join instdomains d on ue.email regexp concat('^.*[.@]', d.domainmask, '$') group by ue.email having count(*) > 1;`.

Comment: @Akina I am using update query which was provided from your side,Is there any way to run that that query without locking table as we are updating table without where.

Comment: Or can I use set session read-uncommitted and run update query.so that I will affects only session. Is it possible?

Comment: *we are updating table without where* ON clause in JOIN is hidden WHERE.